# airflow java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: server, sqlexception, airflow

I am getting this error from airflow:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

The same code works fine in Oozie. The command to run this job in airflow is below.

I added this bold line but still no luck.

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue batch --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml --class com.bcp.test.SimpleBcpJob --executor-memory 1G hdfs://<server_name>/edw/libs/bcptest.jar **hdfs://<server_name>/edw/libs/sqljdbc41.jar** ${nameNode}/edw/data.properties ${nameNode}/edw/test/simple-bcp-job.properties reload
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I assume you specified `nameNode` as an environment variable for airflow? Does running the command in your terminal work?

Comment: That is right. Running the command in my terminal gives the same error. I also replaced ${nameNode} with server name

Comment: /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue batch --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml --class com.bcp.test.SimpleBcpJob --executor-memory 1G hdfs://servername/edw/libs/bcptest.jar hdfs://servername/edw/libs/sqljdbc41.jar hdfs://servername/edw/data.properties hdfs://servernname/edw/test/simple-bcp-job.properties reload